# how to preview core data in a PreviewProvider

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, xcode14

This is in my View

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    ContentView()
.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
.previewDevice("iphone 14 pro")
    }
}
```

This is in my persistence file

```
import CoreData

class PersistenceController: ObservableObject {
     static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            
            let TodoItem = Todo(context: viewContext)
            TodoItem.name = "clean"
            TodoItem.priority = "High"
            
            
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "coreDataToDo")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to load the data that is stored in core data and not that data that I randomly generated in PersistenceController in the for loop. What I am getting in the preview is mostly what is in the forloop

Comment: `static var preview`, use this instead of `shared` in your previews

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: `let persistenceController = PersistenceController.preview`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nothing changed still getting the data from the for loop
 
`let persistenceController = PersistenceController.preview
   ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext,persistenceController
   .container.viewContext)`

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood what you wanted since normally you do _not_ want the data from your store. If that is your case then you should use `shared` as you do in your question. Maybe you somehow have managed to store the data from the loop in the ordinary store my mistake. Maybe you should use some SQLite client and check what you really have stored in the Core Data database

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no worries. Yeah unfortunately I dont think that is it. but thanks for the help anyways. Cheers